# Как заменить модельку Стива в MCBE?

Tags: minecraft

Мне нужно заменить стандартную модельку Стива на другой скин, это нужно сделать ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО через проводник, через сам Майнкрафт я не получу желаемого результата. Где найти эту модельку? В какой папке она лежит?

Answer (score 0):

Вот весь путь у меня. У тебя должно быть также:
AppData\Roaming.minecraft\versions\1.15.2\1.15.2.jar.bak\assets\minecraft\textures\entity\steve.png
Чтобы попасть в Roaming в поиске по компьютеру напиши %AppData%

Comment: Спасибо, на компьютере сделал. А на телефоне как? Через проводник.

Comment: @IvanShevtsov суть такая же: com.mojang>minecraft>textures>entity>steve.png,